# How can I hide other sprites in the background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
input{
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXML2.png") no-repeat -30px -20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

I want to bring that magnifier down a bit. I mean, I want to put it in the middle of the input vertically.

I can do that like this:

```css
    input{
      background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXML2.png") no-repeat -30px -15px;
      height: 30px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<input type = "text" />
```

But as you see that closing-symbol will become apparent. anyway, how can I just change the position of magnifier without displaying other symbols which all are in the same image?

Comment: Why not edit the image and give more space between the images? They seem awfully close to each other.

Comment: Why not just use a different image or at least edit the image to allow more space?

Comment: @Harry I assume because it's an image sprite

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, it is but it can still be edited to have more space right? Or is there something that I am missing here? Not seeing any reason why the image can't be edited. That's most probably the easiest solution for this case.

Comment: @Harry I cannot change the image, because it causes all other symbol be broken and I need to set them new coordinate.

Comment: @Harry More space just means a larger image though, (slightly) negating the point of sprites. I agree it's the simplest solution though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use your existing image with `background-clip`. To do this you'll need to change the `input` styling, but only slightly. You currently have a `height: 30px`, which will need to be changed to `height: 20px` with a `padding: 5px 0;` to give the input a padding on the top and bottom of 5px. this will mean the input remains 30px in height, and displays the icon as you want.

You'll need to use `text-indent` to offset the text so it doesn't overlap the icon too.

```css
input{
      background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXML2.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: -30px -15px;
      background-clip: content-box;
      height: 20px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-indent: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<input type = "text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `background-clip` property to `content-box`. You may have to adjust the padding as well:

```
input{
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXML2.png") no-repeat -30px -15px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 6px 2px;
}
```

Working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/18qf4eno/

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that doesn't involve clipping or padding your input. Wrap the input with a div and use the `::before` psuedo class to position it.

```css
input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-wrap::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXML2.png") no-repeat -30px -20px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!
You can control that with the `background-position`:

```css
#button{
   background-color: #3572b0;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: none;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   font-weight: bold;
   }
#button:hover{
   background-color: #3b7fc4;
   cursor: pointer;
   
}
#field{
   color: #fff;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 3px;
   box-shadow: none;
   background: #1a4067;
   height: 30px;
   width: 170px;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   margin-left: 5px;
   line-height: 1.42857142857143;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: "inherit";
   padding: 2px 30px 2px 10px;
   background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXML2.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: -25px -15px; 
   
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #bbbbbb;
}
*:focus {outline:none !important}
```

```html
<FORM NAME = "form1" >
   <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
      <center><input id="field" type="text" name="text1" value="" autocomplete="off" ></center><br/>
      <center><input id ="button" type="submit" value="Search" ></center>
</FORM>
```

Comment: This is obviously a copy/paste from somewhere else with a lot of unneeded stuff in it. You should really strip out what is important to answer the question. Secondly, a code dump with no explanation is useless.

Comment: I actually just recently worked on this, so when I came across this question I figured I'll share my work. It addresses exactly what the question was. why not give some styling?

Comment: It looks very nice, but to find the actual code that is useful I would have to read 50 lines of code now.

Comment: Also your description is fairly useless, especially as OP is already using background positioning.

Comment: You are right. Will work on it. And btw I like your answer.